# Cordova hook not running when using modules.exports function

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, hook

I created an `after_prepare` hook :

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

module.exports = function(context) {
    ... some code
  console.log('Hey, a hook');
}
```

When I run `cordova build android`, I see in the terminal that it says it is running my hook but it seems like it's not running the module.exports function, because the console.log isn't shown in the console.

Comment: Have you solved this issue? I faced the same problem and haven't found a solution yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this!

I added hook to the config.xml file

```
<hook type="after_prepare" src="hooks/after_prepare/020_add_android_permissions.js"/>
```

and now it executes the code under the `module.exports` function.

Update: here is the working [example](https://gist.github.com/likerRr/db6d4d1faa73c38201787c4098cfeacd)

Comment: from [official documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/7.x/guide/appdev/hooks/#via-hooks-directory-deprecated) hooks directory is deprecated and:

> When using these hooks, they will always be run as executable files, not as loadable JavaScript modules.